# Digital Audio input for Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, input-device

I would like to interface a raspberry pi with the digital outputs of my tv, it has TOSLINK and SPDIF as outputs, and transmit the audio over wifi to rpi receivers

I have already written the software that will stream audio from a raspberry pi over webrtc (overkill I know but I already have written the software for video streaming, modifying the program for audio requires little effort), I only need to solve the problem of capturing the audio from the tv.

Ideally I would like to have a low latency soundcard with digital inputs that I can interface with via ffmpeg, read audio samples from it and then transmit over wifi.

Unfortunately when looking online for such hardware I find nothing.

Does anybody know if I have any options available that are according to my requirements?